# Image gallery and animations like Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to make an image gallery with some nice animations and transitions, much like the new Facebook app provides. I've been searching for tutorials but it seems difficult to find something, or maybe I'm just searching for the wrong things.

I'm more interested in steps towards making this myself, than libraries that provide this functionality, since it would be a very good learning experience, and libraries don't tend to have enough customisability.

The elements I'm specifically interested in are:

- showing a uicollectionview with all images, cropped to squares, centred and scaled (anti-aliased) nicely. Note that the image is not squeezed together to make it square.
- animating seamlessly to a full-screen view, from the cropped image into the original dimensions with a nice black background. The animation is smooth and provides a 'bounce'-effect.
- being able to navigate through the images in fullscreen, allowing pinch zoom and panning in the zoomed images, also much like the photo app. For this, there are several libraries available, but they all provide you with the standard bars on top and bottom, which doesn't really fit my design; I'd like the full-screen view to be more clean and customisable.

Any steps for these elements would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I myself is making this feature in my app now a days. I cannot use `UICollectionView`, as it is only available in >=iOS6. I have created a grid layout manually, and actually it is very easy to implement.

In .h file put this

```
{
    int thumbWidth;
    int thumbHeight;
    int photosInRow;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    int padding;
    int photosCount;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *photoScroll;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *photosArray;
```

In .m file

```
thumbHeight = 73; // 2px is reduced for border
thumbWidth = 73; // 2px is reduced for border
photosInRow = 4;
padding = 4;
xPos = 0;
yPos = 0;
```

You can change above values according to your need. Then populate with images and creating grid layout dynamically like this:

```
photoScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, padding, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
photoScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
photoScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
[photoScroll setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];


photosCount = [photosArray count];
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

for (int counter = 0; counter < photosCount; counter++) {
    // Set x, y positions
    if (counter % photosInRow == 0 && counter !=0) {
        yPos = yPos+thumbHeight+padding;
        xPos = 0;

    } else {
        if (counter != 0) {
            xPos = xPos+thumbWidth+padding;
        }
    }

    UIButton *btnImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [[btnImage layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[btnImage layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

    DBPhotos *photo = (DBPhotos *)[photosArray objectAtIndex:counter];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: photo.thumb];
    [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self options:0
                     success:^(UIImage *image){
                         [btnImage setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     }
                     failure:^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"Error Download image %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                     }];
    [btnImage setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, thumbWidth, thumbHeight)];
    [btnImage setTag:counter];
    [btnImage addTarget:self action:@selector(showFullImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [photoScroll addSubview:btnImage];
}

[photoScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, (ceil(photosCount/photosInRow)*(thumbHeight+padding))+thumbHeight+64)];
[self.view addSubview:photoScroll];
```

You would see that i am using `UIButton` instead of `UIImage`, this is for purpose so that if user taps the image, i could add get and event handler to Show full screen image, at this line:

```
[btnImage addTarget:self action:@selector(showFullImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This code will make an layout like this.

[image]

Now second part of your question. How to show full screen image, with pinch zoom functionality and swipe left/right to display next previous images.
This is actually very easy to implement. I am using 3rd party library [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

Just download it and it is very easy to make Photo Library like UI. Here is what i am doing in `showFullImage` function.

```
- (void)showFullImage:(UIButton*)sender{
    [self.browser setInitialPageIndex:sender.tag];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.browser];
    nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {
    return self.photosArray.count;
}

- (MWPhoto *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < self.photosArray.count) {
        DBPhotos *photo = (DBPhotos *) [self.photosArray objectAtIndex:index];
        return [MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photo.image]];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Tapping on third image will show that in full screen, with left/right arrow or swipe left/right functionality. Also with pinch zoom, and panning zoomed photo.

Hope this helps you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but it's more the details I am interested in. 

For example, when selecting the image in the album, it animated nicely into the full-screen image while gradually changing from a square image into the original aspect ratio. 
The small (square) image is cropped so that the picture is not squeezed together, and it's interpolated so you don't see jagged edges in the image. This images transitions smoothly into a fullscreen image. I'll edit my question to be more specific