# Creating Photo library like iPhone, but UIImage tap event handler not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, photo

Hi i am new to iOS programming.
I need to create an photo library like iPhone native photo app. I have found a library [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)
that provides nearly same UI for photo browsing and its perfect for my requirement. But now i have 2 problems

First is that i need to create a grid layout with thumbnails. Clicking on an thumbnail should display image in full screen with browsing functionality. I tried to dynamically adding `UIImageViews` in `UIScrollView`, but UIScrollView is not scrolling and images are going out of screen.

Second is i could not get any tap handler on `UIImageView` so that i can open an image in full screen. 
Looking for some tips here, i am really stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also developed similar functionality a few days ago for my project.
For tap issue you should use `UIButton` instead of `UIImageView`, it gives you tap action event. For Scrollview not scrolling, just make sure you update [contentSize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) property of `UIScrollView`, otherwise it would not scroll according to your subviews.

Comment: Thanks @khawar, Scrollview problem is solved now, did you also used MWPhotoBrowser?

Comment: Yes i did the same, its easy to implement.

Comment: Can you share you code with me? I am still confused for displaying tapped photo in full screen and then displaying remaining photos with left right buttons.

Comment: You can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780843/image-gallery-and-animations-like-facebook/16783772#16783772

Comment: You just have to make an array of all photos, and provide this array to MWPhotoBrowser delegates method, its simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a shot to this library, it has both features which you are looking for.

https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Khawar I provided you with the start code, Rest you have to see, Complete implementation is not possible over here.

Comment: Thanks @Rajan, i look into this.

Answer (score 2):

For ScrollView scrolling issue you have to increase `scrlViewMain.contentSize` dynamically. Create a `for` loop and put bellow code at the end of loop.

```
scrlViewMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, incermentAsPerYourNeed);
```

For the tapping issue you have to add `TapGesture`. Put bellow code when your `ImageView` creates.

```
   imgView.tag = giveAsPerYourRecordsID;
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
   tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
   tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   tap.delegate = self;
   [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
   [tap release];
```

And bellow your catch method for tapping.

```
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
     UIImageView *tmpImgView = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
}
```